# Gaussian mixture: zero correlation implies independence?

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence, correlation, mixing-variables

Consider two random vectors $X\equiv(X_1, X_2),Y\equiv(Y_1, Y_2)$ distributed as below

1) $X\sim N(\begin{pmatrix}
\mu_{X,1}\\
\mu_{X,2}\\
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
v_{X,1} & 0\\
0 & v_{X,2}
\end{pmatrix})$

2) $Y\sim N(\begin{pmatrix}
\mu_{Y,1}\\
\mu_{Y,2}\\
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
v_{Y,1} & 0\\
0 & v_{Y,2}
\end{pmatrix})$

Consider now the random vector $W\equiv(W_1, W_2)$ whose probability distribution is obtained by mixing $X,Y$ with equal weights $1/2$, i.e.
$$
f_W=\frac{1}{2}f_X+ \frac{1}{2}f_Y
$$
where $f$ denotes the pdf.

Suppose also that $\mu_{X,1}=\mu_{Y,1}$ which implies that $corr(W_1, W_2)=0$ as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2427612/properties-of-mixture-of-2-bivariate-gaussians).

Question: does $corr(W_1, W_2)=0$ implies $W_1$ independent of $W_2$?

---

**EDIT following suggestions below**: Let $M_{W_1, W_2}$ denote the moment generating function of $W_1, W_2$. By construction
$$
M_{W_1, W_2}(s,t)=\frac{1}{2}\exp(s\mu_{X,1}+t\mu_{X,2}+s^2v_{X,1}+t^2v_{X,2})+\frac{1}{2}\exp(s\mu_{Y,1}+t\mu_{Y,2}+s^2v_{Y,1}+t^2v_{Y,2})
$$

[Proposition](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74711/necessary-and-sufficient-condition-on-joint-mgf-for-independence): $M_{W_1, W_2}(s,t)=M_{W_1, W_2}(s,0)\times M_{W_1, W_2}(0,t)$ if and only if $W_1$ independent of $W_2$

In my case
$$
M_{W_1, W_2}(s,0)\times M_{W_1, W_2}(0,t)=\frac{1}{4}\exp(s\mu_{X,1}+t\mu_{X,2}+s^2v_{X,1}+t^2v_{X,2})
$$
$$
+\frac{1}{4}\exp(s\mu_{Y,1}+t\mu_{Y,2}+s^2v_{Y,1}+t^2v_{Y,2})
$$
$$
+\frac{1}{4}\exp(s\mu_{X,1}+t\mu_{Y,2}+s^2v_{X,1}+t^2v_{Y,2})
$$
$$
+\frac{1}{4}\exp(s\mu_{Y,1}+t\mu_{X,2}+s^2v_{Y,1}+t^2v_{X,2})
$$
Notice that 
$$
M_{W_1, W_2}(s,0)\times M_{W_1, W_2}(0,t)=M_{W_1, W_2}(s,t)
$$
if and only if

$\mu_{X,1}=\mu_{Y,1}$ and $v_{X,1}=v_{Y,1}$

or

$\mu_{X,2}=\mu_{Y,2}$ and $v_{X,2}=v_{Y,2}$

Therefore, by the proposition above, $W_1 \perp W_2$ if and only if

$\mu_{X,1}=\mu_{Y,1}$ and $v_{X,1}=v_{Y,1}$

or

$\mu_{X,2}=\mu_{Y,2}$ and $v_{X,2}=v_{Y,2}$.

**Could you tell me whether these derivations are correct and, if wrong, where are the mistakes?**

Comment: What are your thoughts? Which tools do you know, useful to show independence?

Comment: You are not citing "tools (that) you know, useful to show independence".

Comment: @RoyPJ No. You are confusing linear combinations of random variables and barycenters of PDFs.

Comment: @Did thanks, let me start with "if $f_W=f_{W_1}\times f_{W_2}$ then $W_1, W_2$ are independent". But this is a definition and not a tool. I cannot think of other tools at the moment.

Comment: My guess is that you really mean $f_W=f_{W_1}\otimes f_{W_2}$, not $f_W=f_{W_1}f_{W_2}$. But anyway, tools using PDFs are not the only ones...

Comment: Would you be kind to give a more detailed suggestion?

Comment: Apart from statistical testing... I want to show things analytically.

Comment: Hint: Which ways to describe distributions and joint distributions, if not by their PDF?

Comment: Moment generating functions... it's too hard then for me, I'm too bad with those.

Comment: @Did I tried with MGF in the edit above. Does it make any sense?

Comment: Yes, until the paragraph "Therefore W1 and W2 are independent if and only if..." which is unmotivated.

Comment: @Did, OK, I have changed it. Now, is it OK?

Comment: Sorry but no (at present, it is not even clear why you think that these conditions imply independence). Let me suggest that you try to reach, once and for all, **a full solution** based on MGFs, or that you describe clearly an obstacle you meet when doing so, and **then** that you ask users to check it.

Comment: Answered here, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/311731/when-the-two-components-of-a-bivariate-gaussian-mixture-are-independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not in general.  If $W_1$ and $W_2$ are independent the value of  $E( W_1^2 \times W_2)$ would be $EW_1^2\times  EW_2$; and we can compute all three expectations in terms of the problem parameters.  Let's make our life a bit easier by taking $\mu_{X,1}=\mu_{Y,1}=0.$

First, $E W_1^2 W_2 = (E X_1^2 X_2 + EY_1^2  Y_2)/2 = (\nu_{X,1} \mu_{X,2} + \nu_{Y,1}\mu_{Y,2})/2$.  Second, $EW_1^2 = (\nu_{X,1}+\nu_{Y,1})/2.$
Finally, $EW_2 = (\mu_{X,2}+\mu_{Y,2})/2$.

Independence would thus imply 
$$ \frac{\nu_{X,1} \mu_{X_2} + \nu_{Y,1}\mu_{Y,2}}2 =  \frac{\nu_{X,1}+\nu_{Y,1}} 2 \times
\frac{\mu_{X,2}+\mu_{Y,2}}2.$$
If we pick $\nu_{X,1} = 10$ and $\nu_{Y,1}=1$, and pick $\mu_{X,2} = -\mu_{Y,2} = 1$, say, independence would imply 
$$\frac{10-1} 2 = \frac{ 10+1} 2 \times \frac { 1 -1 } 2 = 0.$$

Moral: mixing and independence don't play together nicely.  Mixtures of product measures are typically not product measures; the current case is no exception.